# Do really need a count lock on Multi threads with one CPU core?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, thread-safety, locking, multiprocessing

If i have some code looks like this(Please ignore the syntax, i want to understand it without  a specified language):

```
count = 0

def countDown():
  count += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread1(countDown)
    thread2(countDown)
    thread3(countDown)
```

Here i have a CPU with **only one core**, do i really need a lock to the variable **count** in case of it could be over-written by other threads.

I don't know, but if the language cares a lot, please explain it under **Java、C and Python**, So many thanks.

---

Thanks guys, i now understand i do need a lock. But here's another question, When do i need to use multi threads ?

Since the CPU will execute only one instructor, it seems that multi threads will take more time to manage the threads switch, and can't save the calculation time.

Comment: When the time is right, you'll know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, in general yes. Maybe not in this particular example. But imagine your atomic function would consist of several instructions. The operating system can and does execute many threads *at once*. It executes some steps of one, then switches back to OS which chooses which process/thread to continue. It can start all of your threads and switch between them. Even on one CPU. Then all threads would operate on the same memory addresses and share variables.

Edit: Answer to 2nd question.
When you have one core I can imagine only one case when you would need multithreading. It is when one of your threads can lock and you need to monitor for it or do something else in this time. One practical example would be a sever. If you want to serve multiple clients at the same time you need to switch between them. If you served them in a queue one bad client could hang whole process.

If you are doing computations you might use it to split I/O and computation. But it would need to be a very extreme case to be useful or needed.

Comment: Well, the OS doesn't "execute many threads at once" on a single core CPU. It executes threads one at a time. Each time the scheduler swaps a thread out for another one, that's a context switch. But your point is valid, that one thread may get partway through its work, be suspended, then another thread may try to change the same memory the first thread is using. Imagine thread 1 sets the first half of a long integer value, gets switched out and thread 2 sets the first half of that same integer, then thread 1 comes back and sets the second half, not knowing the first half changed under it. Boom.

Comment: And there are plenty of reasons why a program might need multiple threads on a single-core CPU. For example, that would allow a user interface to remain responsive while background work is done. It won't make the overall program *faster*, just more usable. So many aspects of Win32 have been a pain in the neck forever because of blocking calls, that appear to seize up the whole UI. Even on a single-core CPU, those things would behave better with multiple threads.

Comment: *Well, the OS doesn't "execute many threads at once" on a single core CPU.* logically it does. I never said it does so physically on one CPU. The statement regarding one CPU was only meant for the part saying that system can start all threads, and switch between them. That is why I would say that the safer/"go-to" way to think about it when you design program with many threads, regardless of number of physical processing cores is that threads always are run simultaneously. Because you do not know when and how the context will switch, in general. Of course you can ensure it with some tools.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you probably still need a lock.  Your `countDown` code probably compiles to something like this:

```
load global variable "count" into register x
x = x + 1
save register x into global variable "count"
```

If there is a thread switch in the middle there, then you're in trouble.  You don't actually need a second core to get the bad behavior.

Sometimes `countDown` might compile to an atomic instruction.  For instance, there are such instructions on `x86`, but there's no way I know to guarantee that the compiler uses them (except to write the assembly yourself).

Answer (score 1):

For simple things like increment a counter, instead of using locks, in c you can find atomic functions which do the operation in a thread safe way. GCC defines these atomic builtin functions which are usually wrapped in public function call in what every your particular environment is
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html

Mac OS X defines these for example https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html

These have the potential to be more efficient than lock because they are more limited in functionality than lock.

Answer (score 0):

For the simplest example, we create multiple threads sharing a single variable and performing a single atomic instruction on it. No matter where any thread is interrupted its state is either completely before or completely after the instruction on the shared resource.

In this case, x86 increment is atomic and therefore thread safe. You would not need a lock to maintain consistency or idempotency.

Comment: Are you sure that in java or python you can say its x86 increment ? This example is extremely stripped down. I would say in 99% cases a singular increment will not cause troubles. But in case of interpreted languages I would be worried with more than few instructions or a loop.

Comment: I should have added more qualification. Depending on the language you would also need to specify that the variable is volatile or to give clues to the compiler or interpreter that something should be atomic.

Answer (score 0):

When do you need multi-threading?

To me there are two distinct applications:

- Parallell processing when several threads - ideally just one per core - work on a small part of the overall problem for an extended period of time. The required code and data is small and - in the best of worlds - will fit in the core's L1 and L2 caches. The bottleneck here - if performance is important - will be memory bandwidth and how to use as little of it as possible.
- The other is when there are distinct components of a program the operate more or less independently of one another and where the processing requirements vary over time. One example could be a mail (SMTP) server which is has at least three independent components: an SMTP server to receive mails fron SMTP clients, an SMTP client to send mails to other SMTP servers and a name client to look up the real addresses to which the SMTP client should send the mails.

Answer (score 0):

The lock issue has already been well explained by the other posters.

The other question is fairly easy too - most apps are multithreaded to improve I/O performance with multiple I/O streams that can block.  I'm typing at one now.  The browser must respond to network activity and user input at the mouse and keyboard.  Often, it must do both 'at the same time'.  User input and network comms are very slow and slow, respectively - both block. So, the GUI and network comms run on different threads.  This needs to happen even with only one CPU core and not doing so results in old 'Windows 3.1' style 'hourglass apps' where the GUI is often non-responsive.  Note that this issue of requiring multiple threads also applies to async I/O - something that can seem like it runs on one thread, but is supported by kernel threads/pools - most the blocking is moved into the kernel.

That's it for a single-core box.  You cannot use multiple threads to speed up CPU-intensive calculations, (in fact, you will slow them down, as you realise), but you can use them for high-performance I/O.  Many apps were multithreaded back when we all had single-core Pentiums and Windows 95 - to optimize I/O, not speed up calculations.